# output 'not found' if the item is not in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently working on a project and stuck at this for few hours...
I was asked to find out which month does that particular staff earn the most
it works fine if the staff is in the list, however, it doesn't work if the staff isn't in the list.

Here is what i have got now...

```
salary = ['Ken 1230 2170 1110 1030 1040 1480 1490 1360 1230 1460 1350 1490\n', 
                  'Shi 1190 1180 1500 1300 1250 1400 1150 1110 1240 2090 2000 1030\n', 
                  'John 1360 1370 1090 1190 1200 1490 1360 1240 1170 1370 1030 1390\n', 
                  'Mary 1140 1160 1440 1080 1270 2490 1330 1270 1190 1380 1180 1350\n', 
                  'Bernice 1440 2240 1160 1160 1280 1360 1150 1430 1320 1020 2400 2400\n']
salary = map(str.strip, salary)
salary = map(str.split, salary)
maxlist=[]
month=[]
n=input('Which staff?')
dict_month = {0:'January',1:'February',2:'March',3:'April',4:'May',5:'June',6:'July',7:'Augest',8:'September',9:'October',10:'November',11:'December'}
found_name = False

for i in salary:
    if i[0] == n:
        found_name = True
        del i[0]
        i = list(map(int, i))
        max_value = max(i)
        for j,k in enumerate(i):
            if k == max_value:
                maxlist.append(j)
for i in maxlist:
    if i in dict_month:
        month.append(dict_month[i])

if len(month)==1:
    print(n+' earns the most in '+ month[0])
else:
    print(n + " earns the most in " + ", ".join(month[:-1]) + " and " + month[-1] )

if not found_name:
    print('%s not found' % n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your checking the list month anyway, you need to use your `found_name` earlier:

```
if found_name:
    if len(month)==1:
        print(n+' earns the most in '+ month[0])
    else:
        print(n + " earns the most in " + ", ".join(month[:-1]) + " and " + month[-1] )
else:
    print('%s not found' % n)
```

There is no `month[-1]` if you did not find the name.

Answer (score 1):

You should incorporate error handling into your code:

```
try:
    if len(month)==1:
        print(n+' earns the most in '+ month[0])
    else:
        print(n + " earns the most in " + ", ".join(month[:-1]) + " and " + month[-1] )
except IndexError:
    print('%s not found' % n)
```

Now the program won't crash when unexpected input is entered by the user:

```
Which staff? JOHN DOE
 JOHN DOE not found
>>>
```